# Override a private JS method in Yii Grid View

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I'd like to extend a function in the `YiiGridView` plugin at `yii\framework\zii\widgets\assets\gridview\jquery.yiigridview.js` to add data to the ajax call made by the plugin.

Full source for plugin file can be viewed at: https://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/framework/zii/widgets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js

The following are the solutions I have come upon:

**Solutions**

1. At the moment, I'm using ScriptMap as indicated here:
   http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/31530-override-jqueryyiigridviewjs/
2. I can also opt to use ajaxSend global event to add my own data to every request sent: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/
3. Other methods that indicate that such a functionality can be achieved by overriding `$.fn.yiiGridView.update` function do not apply because as of `Yii 1.1.9` such methods are deprecated.

**Question**

What I'd like to achieve is change:

```
$.ajax(options);
```

to:

```
options = $.extend({}, options, {data: myCustomData});
$.ajax(options);
```

without having to resort to methods 1, 2 or 3. If this is not possible I'd like confirmation of that.

Line number 270 in the plugin file at: https://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/framework/zii/widgets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js#270

Comment: That I'd like to know how to change the specified line to the one I mentioned or whether this can be achieved or not - without having to use the solutions 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, acceptable options is 1 or 3

1: 
+ Uses the core functionality 
+ Only one request for script 
- You can break something 
3: 
+ Safety (did not break anything) 
- Additional request 
- Need to connect in each file

I would choose option number 1

Comment: I never used any of these options but since I didn't state my intentions clearly, I'd say this is as good an answer as any. For details on how I achieved what I intended to achieve, please check my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here just for future reference.

As is evident from the question, I was trying to override the `data` parameter in the ajax call.

I needed to do this to append my custom data, in this case, filters to the `data` object.

There's a better way to achieve this. Rather than try to hack into the code and change the data object, one can use the grid configuration option `'filterSelector' => 'input[name^=filter]',` to select custom filters.

The resulting configuration array will be:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type' => 'striped',
    'id' => 'grid-id',
    'selectableRows' => 0,
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'template' => "{items}\n{pager}",
    'filterSelector' => 'input[name^=filter]'
));
```

The `filterSelector` option automatically appends any data in the matching fields to every ajax call thus eliminating the need to override.